# Completly re-style Jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

Here's the deal: I'm developing a website where people can choose a schedule for their appointment. Problem is that they should choose an hour, but [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is very poorly designed and I can't do what I want.

Here's what I designed with only html-css and little bit of js : 
[link to the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ko4n.jpg)

EDIT: Can I take the datepicker classes and just apply them to my design ?

EDIT#2: I tried to clone the datepicker wrapper but only the one generated by jquery is working (class="date").

Here's the code :

```js
$('.date').datepicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HERE I JUST COPIED THE CODE GENERATED BY JQUERY UI -->
<div class="date hasDatepicker" id="dp1504861075598">
    <div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="display: block;">
      <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"><a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Précédent"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Précédent</span></a><a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" data-handler="next" data-event="click"
          title="Suivant"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Suivant</span></a>
        <div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">octobre</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2017</span></div>
      </div>
      <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span title="lundi">L</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="mardi">M</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="mercredi">M</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="jeudi">J</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span title="vendredi">V</span></th>
            <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="samedi">S</span></th>
            <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="dimanche">D</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="9" data-year="2017"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">31</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- HERE IS MY DATEPICKER WRAPPER THAT DECLARED IN MY JAVASCRIPT -->
  <div class="date"></div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. Override the style by using the classes; with your CSS sheet being referenced BELOW the datepicker CSS in your HTML document.

Comment: I'm trying to do that I'll keep you updated

Comment: that is not working at all

Comment: define "that is not working at all "

Comment: just edited my post, there are more specifications

Comment: And the stylesheets?

Comment: in the other sense, means that when you style what you already get by jquery ui, it's working, but it's so complicated to get what I want.

Comment: So you do not have your own stylesheet??

Comment: When you edit your css file to style the table it's working yes. But, when you want to just copy the class names and paste them into your already styled table, no it's not working

Comment: Can I just get the date from scratch ? Like getting the date for today and every next div I increment ++1 ?  (Date ();)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the technic. I'll just code dates from scratch using [date.js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs)

Just for testing I'm logging out today's date and based on that I add 1 day to this like that I obtain the next day's date. I'm doing the same thing on click, to simulate what I want to do after and it's working.

I hope it's not complicated so i'm pasting the code here so you'll have a better look :

```js
/*global console */

var tdy = (Date.parse("today").toString("MM dd yyyy"));


var monday = Date.parse(tdy.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
var tuesday = Date.parse(monday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
var wednesday = Date.parse(tuesday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
var thursday = Date.parse(wednesday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
var friday = Date.parse(thursday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
var saturday = Date.parse(friday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
var sunday = Date.parse(saturday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);


console.log("Today : "+tdy.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));

console.log("Monday : "+monday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
console.log("Tuesday : "+tuesday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
console.log("Wednesday : "+wednesday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
console.log("Thursday : "+thursday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
console.log("Friday : "+friday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
console.log("Saturday : "+saturday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
console.log("Sunday : "+sunday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));

console.log("===================================");


$(".btn-test").click(function() {

  monday = Date.parse(sunday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
  tuesday = Date.parse(monday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
  wednesday = Date.parse(tuesday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
  thursday = Date.parse(wednesday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
  friday = Date.parse(thursday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
  saturday = Date.parse(friday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);
  sunday = Date.parse(saturday.toString("MM dd yyyy")).addDays(1);

  console.log("Monday : "+monday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
  console.log("Tuesday : "+tuesday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
  console.log("Wednesday : "+wednesday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
  console.log("Thursday : "+thursday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
  console.log("Friday : "+friday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
  console.log("Saturday : "+saturday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
  console.log("Sunday : "+sunday.toString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
  
  console.log("===================================");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-test">Testing</button>
```